# WCF Timeout Exception Server Side

Tags: c#, wcf, service, timeout

I have a `WCF` service with methods that mostly consist of insert operations. Sometimes due to the insert operations take too much time, clients get timeout exception. Is there anyway to catch this timeout exceptions inside `WCF` service (not client)? Can I log this timeout errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than relying on the communication timeout to control the length of service operations, you could control the allowable time to insert in the application.  To that end, you could change your service method to be asynchronous and specify a maximum time-to-run that is less than the transport timeout.

The example in the MSDN “[Cancel Async Tasks after a Period of Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155760.aspx)” may be helpful.